# Why don't I see the binding of my "Visible" property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to modify the visibility of a `CheckBox` in my XAML. I have done this as follows:

XAML excerpt:

```xml
<CheckBox Content="RES" 
          IsChecked="{Binding Unit.Reserved}" 
          Name="chk_Reserved" 
          Visibility="{Binding Res_Visible}"
          ToolTip="Gereserveerd">
</CheckBox>
```

... but, when debugging, if I go to the "Live Visual Tree", I see the following in my properties list:

[image: Live Visual Tree screenshot]

As you can see, there is a binding expression for the `IsChecked` property, but not for the `Visible` property, although this is expected by the XAML.

Does anybody have an idea how this is possible? (Is the `Visible` property not "bindable"?)

Hereby, the definition of the `Res_Visible` property:

```
public class CassetteLevelViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    ...        
    public Visibility Res_Visible { get; set; }
    ...
```

The `Visibility` seems to be a `System.Windows.Visibility`. Is this correct? (I thought there was also an `UIElement.Visibility`, or am I wrong?)

Comment: What is the type of Res_Visible ? If it's a boolean, you have to use a Converter to match the visibility enum.

Comment: `Visible` is definitely bindable. Does it actually *work* for you? Do you see any binding errors in the output? Can you provide a [mcve]? (There's a huge amount of context missing here. Please provide more context not just here, but in future questions.)

Comment: @kipy: I've added the definition of `Res_Visible`. Sorry I forgot this when writing the question.

Comment: The enum is indeed the System.Windows.Visibility one. Is the binding not working ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After quite some experimenting, I've found the solution in the definition of the property:
I have changed:

```
public Visibility Res_Vis {get;set;}
```

Into:

```
public Visibility Res_Vis {get;set;} = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood the problem correctly, you made a binding with the `Res_Visible` property and I suspect you want to change the visibility but when you change it from the `CassetteLevelViewModel` it doesn't work.

To notify the `View` (Xaml) that a property in the `ViewModel` in your case is (`CassetteLevelViewModel`) has changed value, you should use `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `BaseViewModel`.

**If you don't use** , below you can find what you should add in `BaseViewModel`.

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The `OnPropertyChanged()` method notifies the View that the property value has changed.

**If you already use**, you only need to modify your property as in the example below.

```
private Visibility _res_Visibile;
public Visibility Res_Visibile
    {
        get => _res_Visibile;
        set
        {
            _res_Visibile = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a good approach but in the meantime I've found the solution. I mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: I thought you knew that the default for enum `Visibility ` is `Visibility.Visible`.

Comment: No, sorry, I had no idea.